# Angular.js ng-repeat list from *.JSON file

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I begin learning Angular.js and I have first little problem.

This is my **hello.js** file:

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('URL').
  success(function(data) {
  $scope.response = data
 });}
```

The response is a *.json file that I need to parse. JSON looks in a way:

```
"data":[{
   "status":"true",
   "name":"blabla"
},{
   "status":"true",
   "name":"blabla2"
}]
```

In **index.html** file I have `<div ng-controller="Hello">` where I would like to make a list of all JSON's status and name fields.

I have no idea how could I use `ng-repeat` in order to make a list of all components from *.json file. Could you help me? :)

Cheers,

Luke

Comment: I've tried to do it in such a way: `<li>{{response.data.0.name}} :  {{response.data.0.status}}</li>`. And of course it works.. but I have no idea how could I make auto-list.. not a list that I need to change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, and you want to keep your controller as it is, you should do something like:

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="resp in response.data"> 
        My Status: {{resp.status}} and my Name: {{resp.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope I've been helpfull.

Comment: There is no need for a <div> element in a list. You can add the repeat directly to the <li> ex: <li ng-repeat="resp in response.data">My Status: {{resp.status}} and my Name: {{resp.name}}</li>

Answer (score 0):

Example: if you assign the `json` data to a `$scope` variable in your Controller, then this is one possible way of using `ng-repeat` to show it in the View:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='App' ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <table>
     <tr>
         <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in data[0]">{{key}}</th>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="stuff in data">
         <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in stuff">{{val}}</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('App', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.data = [
        {"status":"true",
          "name":"blabla"},
        {"status":"true",
         "name":"blabla2"}
    ];
});
```

Output:
**name** **status**

blabla  true

blabla2 true

EDIT: updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nndc91cp/2/

or you can create a list this way:

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="stuff in data"> {{stuff.status}} : {{stuff.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Output:

- true : blabla
- true : blabla2